# Twilio - How to turn off log collection for phone number verification?

Tags: twilio

The nature of the product we are building requires us to use a phone number to validate a process. Although, we don't want any phone numbers stored in our control.

Is there a way to turn off log collection for verify activity?

Thank you.

I cannot find the option to disable this feature.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Verify does support [number and message redaction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/privacy-message-redaction). But this is a feature you cannot enable on your own. As mentioned in the linked documentation:

> To enable Message Privacy features, you’ll need to [talk to Sales](https://ahoy.twilio.com/message-redaction?_ga=2.82906838.1987125795.1668365386-922382539.1658999163&_gac=1.119087739.1665654460.CjwKCAjw7p6aBhBiEiwA83fGuiGqYzPCTOTQYA9K17DbDce_aCaR8WjxAz67aX0AEngRU232Y5tJYRoCL4AQAvD_BwE). However, there are also a few things to configure in your account to support redaction.

Comment: PS: If you found this answer helpful, please go ahead and use the "checkmark" button to accept it.